# Variable en query que no funciona ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp, gridview

tengo el código que os muestro a continuación que muestra una gridView con notas y una fecha. El problema está en que he comprobado que cuando inserto el valor de la variable **id_Toma** a mano, la función me muestra el gridView correctamente pero cuando intento insertar el valor de esta con la variable (como está en el código que os muestro) no me muestra el gridview. Este está dentro de un modal, dentro de un updatePanel. Depurando el código he podido comprobar que la función recoge los datos bien y que cuando llega el DataSource la tabla se muestra pero no se llega a pintar en el modal. ¿Por qué podría ser?

```
Protected Sub CargarNotasGuardadas()
    Dim c As String = nodoSel.Value
    Dim id_Toma As String = c.Substring(0, c.IndexOf("_"))
    Dim connectionString As String = "conexionalabasededatos"
    Dim query As String = "SELECT notas, fecha_nota FROM [notas-canalJucarTuria] WHERE id_toma = '" & id_Toma & "'"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using selectCommand As New SqlCommand(query, connection)


            connection.Open()

            Dim notasTable As New DataTable()
            notasTable.Load(selectCommand.ExecuteReader())

            If notasTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                GridViewNotas.DataSource = notasTable
                GridViewNotas.DataBind()
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
Protected Sub GridViewNotas_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Eliminar" Then
        Dim idNota As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
        ' Código para eliminar la nota según el ID
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "Editar" Then
        Dim idNota As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
        ' Código para editar la nota según el ID
    End If
End Sub
```